# 2-3-4 tree haskell

Tags: haskell, data-structures, tree, b-tree

I have been given an assignment to implement functions for a 2-3-4 tree in haskell, the problem is, I'm unsure of how to define a 2-3-4 tree. I have been looking around to try and find a pointer in the right direction but that didn't go very well.

Could you suggest a solution?

Comment: You mean, you don't know how the tree works (hint: search for "2 3 4 tree")? Or, you don't know how to implement it in Haskell?

Comment: To paraphrase Wittgenstein: Everything that can be said about trees can be said in a few lines of Haskell. Hence, if the difficulty is that you can define such a tree but not in Haskell, speak your mind and you'll get help.

Comment: yes I meant defining the data type, sorry for not making it clearer

Comment: See [Haskell 2-3-4 Tree](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8549057/1333025).

Answer (score 2):

1. Define a data type for the tree
2. Implement operations on the tree (insertion, deletion and lookup)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2-3-4_tree is a good point to start. There are also some clues at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree

To define a binary tree, you can first write its recursive definition in plain English:

a binary tree with value of type 'x' is either an internal node with a value of type 'x' and two child trees with values of type 'x' or an empty leaf node.

Then it's easy to translate that into Haskell:

```
data BinaryTree x = InternalNode x (BinaryTree x) (BinaryTree x) | LeafNode
```

The 2-3-4 trees differ from binary trees by having 3 kinds of internal nodes instead of one, so you need more alternatives.

Comment: data Tree a = Empty | Tree (Node a) deriving (Show)
data Node a = Node2 a a | Node3 a a a | Node4 a a a a deriving (Show)
I came up with this so far, can you tell if I'm going in the right direction or anything??

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little bit vague, as it's not clear if you want to define the tree structure itself or functions that act on a tree. Since a 2-3-4-tree is just a [B-Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree), you can use `Data.Tree` directly and write functions working on it and enforcing the constraints you like.

If you have to define the tree data type yourself, I'd suggest to define a data type for the nodes that holds (2|3|4)-tuples of nodes and data.

Comment: as it's an assignment, I think he is supposed to define both the datatype and operations himself

Comment: @nponeccop: Sounds plausible, though if he uses a B-Tree, its +/-1 line :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have to define a data type & functions for the tree. I'm sure I can get the functions once I have the data type.

Comment: I thought tuples would be the way to go but I have never used them before so I'm unsure of how to go about it. It's also hard to find notes on how to use tuples in functions on the net.